how to evaluate checkpoints of postgreSQL
I'm newer on postGreSQL. I'm using PG15 on linux server, the server memory is 32G.
the checkpoint_timeout,sharebuffer, wal etc are using default setting on pg_settings.
that means checkpoint_timeout is 5 mins. shared_buffers is 128M.
i used below sql to check
SELECT
total_checkpoints,
seconds_since_start / total_checkpoints / 60 AS minutes_between_checkpoints
FROM
(SELECT
EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (now() - pg_postmaster_start_time())) AS seconds_since_start,
(checkpoints_timed+checkpoints_req) AS total_checkpoints
FROM pg_stat_bgwriter
) AS sub;

It return
total_checkpoints : 147575
minutes_between_checkpoints : 0.08 mins
is that mean checkpoint happens every 0.08 mins?  is it too fast ?
how to performance it?

Start with 8GB and 30 minutes

do you mean set share_buffer=8GB, checkpoint_timeout=30mins?

pg_postmaster_start_time() has no valid role to play in this query.  Stats do not get reset merely upon a (non-crash-recovery) server start up.  They get carried over.  The correct timestamp would presumably be 'stats_reset' from the view itself.

thanks @jjanes, it's just stats_reset .

You must add checkpoints_timed and checkpoints_req to get the total number of checkpoints.
checkpoints_timed should be about a hundred times more than checkpoints_req. If there are too many of the latter, you need to increase max_wal_size (you might find warnings to that effect in the PostgreSQL log).
You should also increase shared_buffers for good performance.
